# Safari - menu to show live tabs open in open windows

Tags: safari, applescript, safari-extensions, tabs

I often have five or six Safari (and Chrome) windows open, each containing several tabs. I often lose track of where a live tab is when I want to return to it.

I can use the Safari window menu option from the main menu to list the names of the active/front tabs in all the open windows, but this doesn’t help me if the tab I’m after is not active/at the front of its window.

Is there an AppleScript or extension that expands on the 'window' menu to list ALL tabs within a window as a child menu item / drop-down?

This would save me minutes of frustration everyday. I’d love a similar solution for Chrome! I've come across https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tree-style-tab/ for Firefox which looks good but I’d prefer that the tree or list is available from the main menu and not within the browser viewport.

Comment: Not a great solution, but there's a Safari extension called [**Sessions**](http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/8247646/sessions/index.html) which shows you a list of all your open tabs, and also keeps a copy of your setup for you. It doesn’t do exactly what you want, but it might be better than nothing.

Comment: "This would save me minutes of frustration every day".  I've changed jobs recently and *everything* is browser based.  I lose *tens* of minutes every day on this.

Answer (score 2):

If you have Alfred 2, there is a [workflow for selecting Safari tabs by typing](http://simonbs.dk/post/41821145647/safari-tabs-workflow-for-alfred-2-0). It includes tabs from all windows, but it doesn't group them by window.

[image]

Comment: The link doesn't work anymore.