# How do I get Safari to search all tabs from all Safari windows in the Tab Overview, instead of only those in the current window?

Tags: safari, shortcut, tabs

When I press the <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>command</kbd><kbd>\</kbd> keyboard shortcut, it goes into 'expose' mode and allows to search thru only the tabs in the current window, not all windows.

It would be super handy to be able to search/display tabs from all windows.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I have been using Sessions for this usage case: https://sessions-extension.github.io/Sessions/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This extension: http://nickvdp.com/tablist/ does allow global search and is awesome. It would also be good if it included iCloud tabs.

I would love it more if it could be invoked from the keyboard or integrated into Spotlight but it's still incredible. The way it just brings that tab+window directly to the front is beautiful.

Comment: This works fantastically well! Thank you so much. Do you happen to know how I could configure a shortcut key in Safari for it to pop up instead of having to click it?

Comment: You can do it through Automator - I googled some instructions. You'll need to allow control of your computer through the Security Preferences Pane for Safari though, which personally I didn't want to do.

Comment: @Siddhartha here's my approach to the keyboard shortcut, it can be expanded to include support for any toolbar button: https://github.com/nickvdp/RecentTabList/issues/13#issuecomment-395111542

Comment: Thanks @MattSephton, that's very cool. I've never tried Alfred but feel that this can be done via BetterTouchTool as well.

Comment: @Siddhartha please let me know your solution once you have it!

Comment: Unfortunately [Safari 13 breaks support for RecentTabList](https://github.com/nickvdp/RecentTabList).

Comment: http://nickvdp.com/tablist/ has been discontinued :-(

Answer (score 4):

The <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>command</kbd><kbd>\</kbd> keyboard shortcut is used to toggle the Tab Overview option in Safari. This can also be accessed via the **View > Show Tab Overview** option via the menubar, or from the Show/Exit Tab Overview icon in the Toolbar.

As you've found, this only displays a visual *thumbnail* of all tabs from the current window, and not all tabs from all Safari windows.

Unfortunately, there's no modifier key you can use to enhance this shortcut, but you *may* find an Extension that does what you want. Extensions don't necessarily work for all versions of Safari, so you may need to experiment a bit to see if one exists that can do what you want.

You can browse for Extensions in the [Safari Extensions Gallery](https://safari-extensions.apple.com).

Finally, you may want to submit some feedback to Apple requesting this feature. For example, you could suggest that including the <kbd>option</kbd> key in the shortcut (i.e. pressing <kbd>option</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>command</kbd><kbd>\</kbd>) works to display all tabs from all windows.

You can submit Safari feedback [here](https://www.apple.com/feedback/safari.html).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I searched the extensions gallery but didn't find anything relevant, would you know a way to search across all tabs in all windows of safari, like the [quick tabs extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/quick-tabs/jnjfeinjfmenlddahdjdmgpbokiacbbb?hl=en) does in chrome?

Comment: I see this answer / question is from 2018. Has there been any update on this, like some official Safari way of searching through all tabs?

Answer (score 3):

"Tabs Switcher" from the App Store works great for me: https://apps.apple.com/us/app/tabs-switcher/id1406718335?mt=12

Comment: I'm curious how many tabs/windows you have open when you use "tabs switcher".  It's quite buggy for me (sometimes not working, sometimes selecting the wrong tab, sometimes crashing) with several dozen windows of several dozen tabs each.

Comment: Works fine for me so far (tested for 1/2 day).
Unfortunately you have max 5 tabs per window in the free version. So this one is useless. However, 3,49€ (one time) is a very fair price tag for the Pro version.

Answer (score 1):

The most immediate way would be to **Window > Merge All Windows** and then do **View > Show Tab Overview**

Comment: What if the merge isn’t desired? I keep separate Safari windows open simultaneously with separate workflows. Once merged there's no way to unmerge into previous state.

Comment: You're right about that.

Comment: Thanks Matt, while that doesn't help with I'm trying to do, it is a handy option to congregate windows, I wish they had a ```Merge selected windows``` option.

Comment: @Siddhartha merge selected windows should be quite easy in AppleScript?

Answer (score 1):

Not a free solution, but [there is an Alfred workflow that enables searching across all the tabs of all the windows](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/92902/10389) in safari.  I just tried it with Safari 13 (after [RecentTabList](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/326709/10389) stopped working).

To use it, you have to:

1. [Download Alfred](https://www.alfredapp.com)
2. [Purchase the Alfred power pack](https://www.alfredapp.com/shop/), and then
3. Download/import the [Search Safari And Chrome Tabs workflow](http://www.packal.org/workflow/search-safari-and-chrome-tabs).

I then modified the workflow to use control-tab as a hot key.

It's not as fast as RecentTabList was but it's *way* faster than searching through 4-dozen open Safari windows and doing a "search open tabs" on each one to find one of your hundred+ open tabs.

Comment: Still works on Safari 14

Comment: Still works on Safari 15

Comment: Still works on Safari 16

Answer (score 1):

A working solution using AppleScript, posted at [https://hea-www.harvard.edu/~fine/OSX/safari-tabs.html](https://hea-www.harvard.edu/%7Efine/OSX/safari-tabs.html).
Copy-pasting it here for an answer to be self-contained (and just in case a source page becomes unavailable).
Using it myself.

```
set question to display dialog ("Find Safari tab:") default answer ""
set searchpat to text returned of question

tell application "Safari"
    set winlist to every window
    set winmatchlist to {}
    set tabmatchlist to {}
    set tabnamematchlist to {}
    repeat with win in winlist
        set ok to true
        try
            set tablist to every tab of win
        on error errmsg
            --display dialog name of win as string
            set ok to false
        end try
        if ok then
            repeat with t in tablist
                if searchpat is in (name of t as string) then
                    set end of winmatchlist to win
                    set end of tabmatchlist to t
                    set end of tabnamematchlist to (id of win as string) & "." & (index of t as string) & ".  " & (name of t as string)
                    --display dialog name of t as string
                else if searchpat is in (URL of t as string) then
                    set end of winmatchlist to win
                    set end of tabmatchlist to t
                    set end of tabnamematchlist to (id of win as string) & "." & (index of t as string) & ".  " & (name of t as string)
                    --display dialog name of t as string
                end if
            end repeat
        end if
    end repeat
    if (count of tabmatchlist) = 1 then
        --display dialog "one!"
        set w to item 1 of winmatchlist
        set t to item 1 of tabmatchlist
        set current tab of w to t
        set index of w to 1
    else if (count of tabmatchlist) = 0 then
        display dialog "No matches"
    else
        set whichtab to choose from list of tabnamematchlist with prompt "The following tabs match, please select one:"
        set AppleScript's text item delimiters to "."
        if whichtab is not equal to false then
            set tmp to text items of (whichtab as string)
            set w to (item 1 of tmp) as integer
            set t to (item 2 of tmp) as integer
            set current tab of window id w to tab t of window id w
            set index of window id w to 1
        end if
    end if
end tell
```

To launch this script, as described in the answer to this question (below is pretty much a copy-paste from that answer for this part): [How do I assign a keyboard shortcut to an AppleScript I wrote?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/175215/how-do-i-assign-a-keyboard-shortcut-to-an-applescript-i-wrote)

1. Open Automator.
2. Make a new Quick Action.
3. Make sure it receives 'no input' at all programs.
4. Select Run Apple Script and type in your code.
5. Save
6. Go to System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts. Select Services from the sidebar and find your service. Add a shortcut by double clicking (none)
7. Finally go to System Preferences > Security > Privacy > Accessibility and add Automator and the preferred app to run the shortcut.

Please note, it's important to test if your shortcut doesn't have a conflict with other Safari shortcuts. For inst. you cannot use `Command+Shift+S`, because Safari just opens "Save page as" on it.
And in may case some other key combinations didn't work while Safari was active, but worked when some other applications were active, for inst. `Command+Option+S`, `Command+Shift+F` - when I was in Safari those shortcuts just didn't launch the script. One keys combination that worked for me in Safari is **`Command+Option+\`**

P.S. tablist (http://nickvdp.com/tablist/) was a good solution, too bad it's no longer working

Comment: This is an excellent approach.